# How to regenerate the “Don’t Ask Me” warning alert

Tags: xcode

How to reset the “Don’t Ask Me” Warning in Xcode. I have chosen “Do not show this message again” in the alert alert box (Stop “Your Project”, An instance of ”Your project is already running. Choose launch to terminate and launch  a new instance) while app running. 
Although, I want to reset this alert back to the previous state as shown below. [image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well. You can go Xcode -> Preferences -> General -> Click “Reset Don’t Ask Me Warnings” button (Which is located in last).

[image]